# CSS animation acting multiple times when fired on hover

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a very simple but very annoying problem. I have a div with class card and on hover, it should run a simple animation-to rotate3d(360deg) the whole div.

```
.card:hover{
    animation: fullTurn 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@keyframes fullTurn{
    0% {transform: rotateY(0deg);}
    100% {transform: rotateY(360deg);}
}
```

When I hover over the div, I expect it to simply rotate the whole div 360 degree in 3d style. The thing that actually happens is that when I hover over the div,the animation starts, stops in the middle and starts again. It happens many times and after some time, it completes the animation as expected. I want it to complete[image: Animation not running properly] the animation in single go.

Comment: A codepen reproduction would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, Parneet Dixit, 
with the given information you provide. I belive the problem is how the animation is triggered, you make an animation to act on hover about the y-axis, so at a particular moment that div loss its contact with mouse pointer in-between animation and that when the animation starts again, so you need to change the trigger event for the animation other than hover like "onClick"

Answer (score 0):

Well! I finally have found the solution. This problem was raised due to the reason stated by @GautamSaharan.

> I believe the problem is how the animation is triggered, you make an animation to act on hover about the y-axis, so at a particular moment that div loss its contact with mouse pointer in-between animation and that when the animation starts again.

To deal with this issue, I have made an outer div and placed the existing div inside that.

```
<div class="outerDiv">
     <div class="card">
          <!--The content of the div-->
     </div>
</div>
```

Now, after updating the CSS a little bit, it will work all fine.

```
.outerDiv:hover .card{
    animation: fullTurn 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@keyframes fullTurn{
    0% {transform: rotateY(0deg);}
    100% {transform: rotateY(360deg);}
}
```

On hovering on the outer div, the inner div will rotate but the contact of the cursor will not be broken.